Local file path visible for user in case of error
I build a Blazor Web App (server side rendering) with C# and .NET 8. The app is hosted on an Azure App Service. If an error occurs and I open the browser dev tools, I can see a detailed error message. This is great!
But I don´t understand, why I can see the local path of the *.razor.cs file?
See screenshot:

I am confused why the Azure App Service knows where my local Visual Studio project is located. The app is published via Visual Studio directly and built in "Release" mode.
From a developer perspective, it´s great because we all love detailed error messages. But this is maybe to much information for an attacker or something...
Any thoughts?

If possible, share your GitHub repository?

Is your issue resolved?

No, i can´t share the repo, sorry! But deleting the *.pdb file did the trick.

As other user said you are getting this file path in the error from the pdb file. The below link it is explained in detail.
Azure Error Referencing Local Path
To avoid this information to displayed you could follow below ways:
1)You can delete the pdb files
2)You can set the environment variable to production and manage error handling as shown here:
On the azure app service set environment variable to ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT and value Production
In the program.cs file use this code:
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error"); // Redirects to a generic error page
    app.UseHsts();
}

This will show detailed error information during development. In production, this redirects to a generic error page (Error.cshtml), preventing detailed exception details (like file paths) from being shown.
For more detail you could refer document about how to handle error in blazor and how to secure blazor app:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-8.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/server/?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio

This helped a lot, thanks! I deleted the *.pdb file in the Azure App service and received a more generic error message.

@FabianHolz glad it helped

I would assume that the local file path displayed in the error message comes from a .pdb file. Generally, people tend to exclude these files when deploying to production for this very reason. PDB files are symbol files that are used for debugging.
You can configure your build output not to produce these files, or you can delete them manually.

Thanks @ThomasLundgren for your answers. It comes from the *.pdb file. I deleted it and received a more generic error message.
